# insert image into sheet will not change the usedrange

Tags: c#, excel-interop

I'm developing c# Excel Add-In solution. I used the following code to insert image into cell.

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook wb= Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWorkbook;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet activeWorksheet= wb.ActiveSheet;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range usedRage = activeWorksheet.UsedRange;
int nextRow = usedRage.Rows.Count + 2;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range newRange = activeWorksheet.Rows[nextRow];
...
Image oImage = Image.FromStream(ms);
System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard.SetDataObject(oImage, false);
activeWorksheet.Paste(newRange);
wb.Save();
```

The issue is the usedrange always is the same. So the image will not be placed on the right position. It seemed that the usedrange will not be updated after inserting image in the specific range.

Comment: I am a little confused as to where you got the idea that you can … _”insert image into cell”_ … ? … Technically when you add an image to a worksheet, it is never “inserted” into a particular cell. You can use a `Range` to define “where” the picture is placed, however the picture is simply pasted “ON TOP” of the range and is not really a part of any particular cell. Bottom line is that adding a picture to the worksheet is NOT going to change the worksheets `UsedRange` value.

Comment: @JohnG Understand it. So, I just want to put the image on the specific position according to the previous image' position . What's the best practice?

Comment: Well… I cannot speak about “best” practices other than don’t use interop… however, I am aware you may not have a choice and I am not sure if a third-party library would make it any easier given this context. After a little testing, it became clear that we would need to implement something that checks the last used cell INCLUDING cells that may have a picture on top of the cell. If you had numerous pictures at the end of the worksheet, then this may not be trivial.

Comment: Have you considered simply adding something to the cell directly below the picture “after” you have pasted the picture? Simply “formatting” the cell without any text, below the picture, will then include that cell in the `UsedRange`, which will solve your current `UsedRange` issue. This approach still comes with its own drawbacks like… if the pictures in the worksheet we not placed by our code and the formatted cell is not present… or the user deletes the “empty” cell. I am confident other issues are present, However it may work.

Comment: I can proffer a simple yet crude solution using the idea above. There are two methods. The `AddPictureToBottom` method takes a worksheet and an image and places the image at the end of the current used range and also formats the cell below the image so that when `UsedRange` is called again it will include the cells with the picture. The second method calculates “which” row is after the bottom of the picture which tells us which row/cell to format.

Answer (score 0):

After trying a lot of ways, I found a good way to achieve my target. I'm not sure if it's the best practice, but It can help me insert images to the correct position according to the previous image.

The following is the code sample:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook wb = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWorkbook;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet activeWorksheet = wb.ActiveSheet;

Excel.Shapes sps = activeWorksheet.Shapes;

...
foreach (Excel.Shape sp in sps)
{
    var rowNo = sp.BottomRightCell.Row;
}
...
```

We can calculate and get the max row number from the above code. Then we can insert new image at the next row range. Hope it will be helpful to other developers who're facing the similar issues.